# Redirect GET requests only in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing a custom product landing page for WooCommerce that allows the customer to select one of several bundles for a parent product. In order to add the bundle to the user's cart, I use a form that POSTs to the URL of the product / bundle.

The issue is that I need to redirect users from the original bundle / product pages to the appropriate product landing page. The only solution I've found so far is the wp_redirect() function, but that redirects ALL requests to the given location, which includes the POST requests needed to submit the form.

How can I redirect only GET requests to these pages so that users can't visit them, but my product landing page can submit POST requests?

Edit: For clarification, I'm not familiar with WordPress's routing structure so I don't know how to access an incoming request. If I had access to the request, redirecting it conditionally would be trivial.

Comment: Why not checking a specific GET / POST parameter to ensure that the request should be redirected or not?

Comment: That's what I'd like to do, but I'm not familiar with WordPress's routing structure.  Where would I have access to the incoming request to implement something like that?

Comment: You can use the `template_redirect` action hook for example: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/